# Adding custom methods to a subclassed NSManagedObject

Tags: cocoa, inheritance, core-data, subclass

I have a Core Data model where I have an entity A, which is an abstract. Entities B, C, and D inherit from entity A. There are several properties defined in entity A which are used by B, C, and D.

I would like to leverage this inheritance in my model code. In addition to properties, I am wondering if I can add methods to entity A, which are implemented in it's sub-entities.

For example:

1. I add a method to the interface for entity A which returns a value and takes one argument
2. I add implementations of this method to A, B, C, D
3. Then, I call `executeFetchRequest:` to retrieve all instances of B
4. I call the method on the objects retrieved, which should call the implementation of the method contained in B's implementation

I have tried this, but when calling the method, I receive:

> [NSManagedObject methodName:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance

I presume this is because the objects returned by `executeFetchRequest:` are proxy objects of some sort.

Is there any way to leverage inheritance using subclassed NSManagedObjects?

I would really like to be able to do this, otherwise my model code would be responsible for determining what type of NSManagedObject it's dealing with and perform special logic according to the type, which is undesirable.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It should work. The objects returned by `executeFetchRequest:` are real instances of `NSManagedObject`s (or subclasses thereof.)
The steps to use custom classes in CoreData are as follows. Say you have entities A and B, where B inherits from A. 
Then you need two custom classes as

```
@interface A:NSManagedObject{
}
-(void)someMethod:(NSString*)a;
@end;
@interface B:A{
}
-(void)someMethod:(NSString*)a;
@end;
```

Then set them in the XCode data modeler as shown:

[image: screenshot of XCode modeler]

This way, the CoreData automatically assigns the correct class to the `NSManagedObject` when it is fetched from the database.

Comment: Thanks so much! My data model was using NSManagedObject; I hadn't even realized that I needed to specify the class name, works perfectly!

Comment: I'm not seeing the screenshot in this answer -- could someone replace it (Yuji)?

Comment: Unfortunately the screenshot is not available! :(

Comment: Hi, I added it back. It was posted when the SO didn't host the image itself, and my personal server changed URL... Please note that it uses an old version of Xcode so it might look a bit different.

Answer (score 18):

If you're getting that exception, it means Core Data is not using your custom class. The key here is `NSManagedObject` -- that's the object Core Data created for the objects in your data store.

If you haven't already, you'll need to create a class that inherits from `NSManagedObject`, add your custom methods there, and then set entity `A` to use your custom class in the object model tool. If entities `B`, `C`, `D`, etc. have specific behaviors, you should subclass the class you created for entity `A` and assign those entities to use the subclasses too.

Essentially,  you have a parallel hierarchy: one hierarchy of entities, and another of classes. You'll likely end up with entity `X` and class `X` for each entity in your object model.

Comment: Thanks, you had the right answer, but Yuji provided me with the screenshot that really pointed me in the right direction. If I could accept your answer as well, I would.

Comment: So easy to forget about xcdatamodel when you change the name of an entity class!!  Your answer saved me a lot of time!! Thanks so much :-)

Comment: +1 Thanks so much for the tip "set entity to use your custom class in the object model tool". For me, I didn't use the auto-generated class, so I'd skipped this step!

Answer (score 2):

After trying lots of solution calling isMemberOfClass on my NSManagedObject subclass before trying to use my custom method made the trick.

```
[thing isMemberOfClass:[Thing class]];
[thing customMethod]; //was getting unrecognized selector sent to instance here before
```

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me. I believe this has to do with the fact that my CoreData code is all inside a static library as opposed to directly in the main application, but I'm not completely sure about that.

Comment: this did trick for me as well, as my core data code is in static library and I use it as sub project in an other app +1 for your answer  @micheal23

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error for the same underlying reason, but it came about in a different situation and a different cure.  Your suggestion helped me a lot!

Originally I had created my class implementing my entry by hand.  I didn't know there was an Xcode menu for this.  I think the link was never there!  So it wasn't until I had added and began testing the new custom methods (not setter/getters) that I started to get the error.

My solution was to change the name of my class, have Xcode re-create the class for my entry via `Editor->Create NS Mangage Object....`  Then cut and paste in the old code into the new class.  No difference in code!

Xcode seems to have some kind of internal link that is not apparent in the code.